# Why is the Galois closure of $K/F$ the composite of the Galois conjugates of $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K/F$ is a field extension with Galois closure $L$, and let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/F)$. Why is $L$ the same as the composite of the Galois conjugates $\sigma(K)$ for $\sigma\in G$?

I know that $K$ is certainly contained in some Galois extension, and then the Galois closure of $K/F$ is just the intersection of all Galois extensions of $F$ containing $K$. That's the definition I've always seen. Why is the above characterization the same?

I'm curious because it shows up in the technical lemma preceding Abel's solvability by radicals theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Galois closure of an extension $K/F$ in a fixed algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ is a field which is minimal among all Galois extensions of $F$ containing $K$. One can prove there is a unique such field, which will be the intersection of all Galois extensions of $F$ containing $K$.

Suppose $L$ is the Galois closure of $K/F$. Then $L$ must contain all ${\rm Gal}(L/F)$-conjugates of $K$ and hence $L$ must contain the compositum $C=\prod_\sigma \sigma K$. Conversely, by the primitive element theorem we may write $K=F(\theta)$ where $\theta$ satisfies its minimal polynomial $m(x)\in F[x]$. Since $C$ is the splitting field of $m(x)$ it is normal, if we assume further that it is separable (which is the situation for number fields in particular) then $C/F$ is Galois containing $K$. But $L$ is minimal with these properties and $L$ contains $C$, so we must therefore have $L=C$.

Comment: Thanks. And to be sure, $C$ is the splitting field of $m(x)$ since $\{\sigma(\theta):\sigma\in G\}$ is the set of roots since $G$ acts transitively on them?

Comment: @Hobbie yes. ${}$

Comment: Why can you use the primitive element theorem without justifying it is a separable extension? Or we should assume $K/F$ is separable in addition?

Comment: If $K/F$ isn't separable, then no $L \supset K$ can be Galois.

Comment: Is this result still true when characteristic isn't zero?